# copy over rows a specific number of times based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

Hey guys I have a data frame in python which looks something like the following

| FirstName | MiddleName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | J | Jones |
| Anthony | K | White |
| Ravi | K | Khanna |

I want to add a column for year and repeat the rows with the number of years, something like

| FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | J | Jones | 2020 |
| Jim | J | Jones | 2021 |
| Jim | J | Jones | 2022 |
| Anthony | K | White | 2020 |
| Anthony | K | White | 2021 |
| Anthony | K | White | 2022 |
| Ravi | K | Khanna | 2020 |
| Ravi | K | Khanna | 2021 |
| Ravi | K | Khanna | 2022 |

Does anyone have any advice on how I can go about doing this on Pandas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For all of the first name, you want to add three rows with three columns? Or for some of them you need two or one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
l = [2020, 2021, 2022]
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(len(l))).assign(Year=np.tile(l, len(df)))
```

Output:

```
  FirstName MiddleName LastName  Year
0       Jim          J    Jones  2020
0       Jim          J    Jones  2021
0       Jim          J    Jones  2022
1   Anthony          K    White  2020
1   Anthony          K    White  2021
1   Anthony          K    White  2022
2      Ravi          K   Khanna  2020
2      Ravi          K   Khanna  2021
2      Ravi          K   Khanna  2022
```

Details, use `reindex` and `repeat` to expand dataframe to get the appropriate number of rows, then add a column 'Year' with `assign` and `np.tile`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
years = [2020,2021,2022]
df['Year'] = [years]*len(df)
df = df.explode('Year')
```

Output:

```
    FirstName   MiddleName  LastName    Year
0   Jim         J           Jones       2020
0   Jim         J           Jones       2021
0   Jim         J           Jones       2022
1   Anthony     K           White       2020
1   Anthony     K           White       2021
1   Anthony     K           White       2022
2   Ravi        K           Khanna      2020
2   Ravi        K           Khanna      2021
2   Ravi        K           Khanna      2022
```

Comment: That's a cool way of doing it too.  Using explode.  I like this.  +1